# Why can't I see the bootcamp drive from Mac OS?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, boot-camp

I have a MacBookPro.  Primarily use Windows via Bootcamp but occasionally have to dive into the Mac side of things.

One thing I've noticed is that in Mac OS it only offers its own partition in the list of Devices in the Finder.  So how exactly do I access the Bootcamp (windows) partition from the Mac?  I don't see it anywhere.

I think in the past I saw the Windows partition, but I can't tell for certain, since I don't go there all that often.  This feature was always on OSX, right?

I tried to go to the Disk Utility and it doesn't seem to recognize the bootcamp partition:

[image]

If I click on this disk0s4, i see the following:

[image]

If I click on Verify Disk, it brings up this error and tells me to Repair Disk.  I am afraid to do that for fear of losing my Windows Partition.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try opening the Finder, and under Preferences look for Devices and see if clicking some of those settings opens your Bootcamp volume from the desktop.